# The page isn’t redirecting properly in custom module

Tags: magento2, customer-account, redirection

I have created the custom module for custom login, but when I open the below link, it's not redirecting properly.

```
http://localhost/magento/custommodule/
```

Below is my route file code and path:

**app\code\Vendor\Custommodule\etc\frontend\routes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="custommodule" frontName="custommodule">
            <module name="Vendor_Custommodule" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

layout file path:

**app\code\Vendor\Custommodule\view\frontend\layout\pressroom_index_index.xml**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" layout="2columns-left">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="page.main.title">
            <action method="setPageTitle">
                <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">pressroom</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
           <container name="customer.login.container" label="Customer Login Container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="login-container">
                <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Login" name="customer_form_login" template="form/mycusromlogin.phtml">
                    <container name="form.additional.info" as="form_additional_info"/>
                </block>
            </container>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**app\code\Vendor\Custommodule\Controller\Index\Index.php**

```
<?php
 
namespace Vendor\Custommodule\Controller\Index;
 
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
 
class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $_resultPageFactory;
    protected $urlInterface;

 
    public function __construct(Context $context, 
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
         UrlInterface $urlInterface,
         \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $session)
    {
        $this->_resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->urlInterface = $urlInterface;
         $this->_session = $session;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
 
    public function execute()
    {     
        $url = $this->urlInterface->getUrl('custommodule/index/index');

        // Create login URL
        $login_url = $this->urlInterface->getUrl('custommodule/index/index', array('referer' => base64_encode($url))
                            );
        // Redirect to login URL
        /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
       
        if(!$this->_session->isLoggedIn()) {  
            //echo $login_url.'<br /> here'; die;
            $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
            $resultRedirect->setUrl($login_url);
            return $resultRedirect;
        }else{
            //echo $login_url; die;
            $resultPage = $this->_resultPageFactory->create();
            return $resultPage;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *not properly rendered*? Not at all or is an exception being generated?

Comment: It's not redirecting properly. it's showing the `The page isn’t redirecting properly` error.

Comment: Sorry I have misread your title as *rendered* not *redirected*, shame on me

Comment: Ok, please see my code what I am doing. I want to add `referer key` with route URL, so that when user will login they will redirect on same page after the login.

Comment: Is the login URL really custommodule/index/index? It seams like you are redirecting to yourself? Maybe change the second `custommodule/index/index` to `customer/account/login`

Comment: I can't do that because the `customer/account/login` already running with different design. so that's why I am creating my custom module to achieve that functionality.

Comment: I think the problem with this syntax `$resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
            $resultRedirect->setUrl($login_url);`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60504/discussion-between-ooxi-and-magedev0688).

Answer (score 0):

You should change layout name `pressroom_index_index` to `custommodule_index_index`

Not test you but you should try redirect like below

```
public function execute() {
--- concat ---

$resultRedirect->setUrl('custommodule/index/index');

--- concat ---
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I had solved this issue at my end.